# Unable to use a escape sequences in a variable in a sed command

Tags: sed, quoting, colors

I'm using `sed` to highlight a column in the output of a `ps` command, and it works fine if I hard code the color code. However, the color needs to be dynamic, so I tried moving it to a variable, and referencing the variable in the sed command, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

```
# Works
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu | head  | sed -e $'s/ *[^ ]* /\033[1;33m&\033[0m/6'
```

But when I move the `\033[1;33m` and `\033[0m` to a variable, and referencing it in the command (a few different ways), it doesn't work at all:

```
# None of the following work
fg_normal="\033[0m"
fg_yellow="\033[1;33m"

ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu | head  | sed -e $'s/ *[^ ]* /'$fg_yellow'&'$fg_normal'/6'
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu | head  | sed -e $'s/ *[^ ]* /'"$fg_yellow"'&'"$fg_normal"'/6'
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu | head  | sed -e $"s/ *[^ ]* /$fg_yellow&$fg_normal/6"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried double quoting the $fg_ in the sed statement variables?

Comment: Dude, why are you complicating your life when all you have to do is go back to the Q you linked to in your earlier question and follow the instructions in Stéphane's answer ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
fg_normal=$(echo -e "\033[0m")
fg_yellow=$(echo -e "\033[1;33m")
```

or with tput:

```
fg_normal=$(tput sgr0)
fg_yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `printf`'s `%b` specifier to assemble the sed command, preserving the correct backslash escape sequences:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu | head  | 
    sed -e "$(printf 's/ *[^ ]* /%b&%b/6' "$fg_yellow" "$fg_normal")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the `$'...'` is a feature of the shell to write escaped characters. A `$'\033'` is an actual escape <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Therefore, you need to move the `$' '` from inside the sed command:

```
sed -e $'s/ *[^ ]* /\033[1;33m&\033[0m/6'
```

To the actual variables you will use:

```
fg_normal=$'\033[0m'
fg_yellow=$'\033[1;33m'
```

With that simple change, this (no `$'` needed now) will work (watch the correct quoting inside-outside the single quotes <kbd>'</kbd>):

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,user,tty,%cpu,%mem,vsize,command --sort -%cpu |
head -n 10  |
sed -e 's/ *[^ ]* /'"$fg_yellow"'&'"$fg_normal"'/6'
```